# Updating Gridview Parsing Textbox to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview, updating

I'm using an ajax calendar extender inside an editTemplate for a gridview. When updating, I get a message that the database could not be updated because the String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I think it's mixing up the month, day because it will work for dates that are under the 12th of the month. How do I parse the text to a datetime so that the update will work?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="dogId,treatmentId" DataSourceID="VaxDataSource" CssClass="table" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" EditText="edit" UpdateText="update" />

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="reminder" SortExpression="reminderDate">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reminderDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                                    TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reminderDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="treatmentDate" HeaderText="treatment" 
                            SortExpression="treatmentDate" readOnly="false"/>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="treatment" SortExpression="recievedDate">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("recievedDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox2_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                                    TargetControlID="TextBox2">
                                </asp:CalendarExtender>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("recievedDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="treatment" 
                            SortExpression="description" readOnly="true"/>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VaxDataSource" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dogDBConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT Treatment2Dog.dogId, Treatment2Dog.treatmentId, Treatment2Dog.reminderDate, Treatment2Dog.treatmentDate, Treatment2Dog.recievedDate, Medical_Treatment.description FROM Medical_Treatment INNER JOIN Treatment2Dog ON Medical_Treatment.id = Treatment2Dog.treatmentId WHERE (Treatment2Dog.dogId = @dogID)" 
                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Treatment2Dog SET reminderDate = @reminderDate, recievedDate = @recievedDate WHERE (dogId = @dogID) AND (treatmentId = @treatmentId)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="dogID" QueryStringField="dogid" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="reminderDate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="recievedDate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="dogID" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="treatmentId" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an AjaxEntender you are are also bound to be using a ScriptManager. Ensure that your script manager has these two parameters set:

`EnableScriptGlobalization="true"` and `EnableScriptLocalization="true"'` so that is looks like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
    EnableScriptLocalization="true">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

If you require further assistance please post the entire block of markup so we can view the surrounding controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a handler for the RowUpdating event on the gridview:

```
OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
```

In the handler function, you may be able to set the value of the `treatmentDate` and `reminder` fields to the correct format.

Check this out for more info: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)